# Regex for simple shuffle using String.replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

What would be the regex for `replaceAll()` that swaps adjacent chars?

For example, to turn this:

```
abcdefg
```

into this:

```
badcfeg
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`"abcdefg".replaceAll("(.)(.)", "$2$1")`

This will return `badcfeg`.